# Ansible with_sequence output format 01 instead of 1

Tags: ansible

I have the following Ansible code:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    newvms: "{{ (newvms | default([])) + [ item ] }}"
  with_sequence: "start=1 count=3 format=%d"
```

What I get with the above code: `1, 2 ,3`

What I want to get: `01, 02, 03`

Is this possible?
Appreciate the input!

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Python printf-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting)

```py
    %02d
```

Comment: Thanks so much Vladimir, that fixed it. That helps a lot as well as the link.